# Query with OR on 2 tables

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to do is list if an agency nurse works in hospital H2 **or** has a qualification Q3 or both.

I have two tables `Agency_A` & `Qualification`

```
Agency_A     
Nurse      Hospital
Thomas     H1  
Taylor     H2  
Evans      H3  
Davies     H2  

Qualification
Nurse      Qualification
Thomas     Q2
Taylor     Q3
Evans      Q4
Freeman    Q3
```

So I'm looking for

```
|TAYLOR  |                          {as she works in H2 and has qualification Q3}
|FREEMAN |                          {as she has qualification Q3}
|DAVIES  |                          {as she works in H2 etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to cover it:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(Qualification.Nurse, Agency_A.Nurse)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Nurse 
  FROM Agency_A 
  WHERE Hospital = 'H2') Agency_A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Nurse 
  FROM Qualification 
  WHERE Qualification = 'Q3') Qualification
ON Agency_A.Nurse = Qualification.Nurse
```

This covers the case where a nurse is in one table but not the other.

Comment: Hi thats a great help - much appreciated indeed - thanks again